# Xed2-Intel64 library - Issue MOV opcode

Tags: c++, intel, disassembly

I have an issue with the C++ xed2-Intel64 library.
Some opcodes are not well cut, 
for example the MOV opcode with objdump :

49 89 d1  : mov rsp rbp

But I obtain with xed_decode and the mode  :

```
xed_decoded_inst_set_mode(&xedd, XED_MACHINE_MODE_LEGACY_32, XED_ADDRESS_WIDTH_64b);
```

49  : DEC eflag eax
89 d1  : MOV esp ebp

How can I avoid that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `XED_MACHINE_MODE_LONG_64` flag instead of the `XED_MACHINE_MODE_LEGACY_32` to decode the instruction using 64-bit instruction decoding rules.